# Unable to Authenticate googleCloudStorageR/googleAuthR

Tags: r, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to authenticate gcs in R using googleCloudStorageR and googleAuthR.

I have all the necessary APIs enabled on gcp.

I am able to authenticate with bigrquery when i run query_exec(sql,project,use_legacy_sql = FALSE), the browser opens up, the token is cached and everything works fine.

But when i try to do the same with googlecloudstorageR gcs_auth() or gar_auth() with googleAuthR. I keep getting the following error.

Error: option('googleAuthR.client_id') has not been set

I do not right now have permissions to create credentials from the API page. But i do not understand why i can auth bigrquery without having to do any of this but not googlecloudstorage through gcs_auth or gar_auth.

Also can i use the same client id and secret from the bigrquery .httr/oauth file to auth googlecloudstorage by changing the scope ?

Edit:
I am using it at work, so i do not have privileges to create credentials from the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials page.

Code:

```
library(bigrquery)

project <- "mtproject"
sql <- "SELECT * FROM `myproject.Superstore.orders`"
data <- query_exec(sql,myproject,use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
```

When i run the above code, the browser opens up and gives me a token which i then copy and paste into R.

But when i try to authenticate using the following code for googleAuthR, nothing happens and i get the error.

```
library(googleAuthR)
2019-05-21 14:10:34> No environment argument found, looked in GAR_AUTH_FILE
Warning message:
package ‘googleAuthR’ was built under R version 3.5.3 
> gar_auth(new_user=TRUE)
Error: option('googleAuthR.client_id') has not been set
```

I did not set any client id for bigquery auth but that works, why is gar_auth not working ?

Comment: You need to show the code you are using. Without clear details and error messages you are either asking volunteers to invest a lot of time or guess. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: From which API page are you trying to create credentials? 

What message are you seeing when you are trying to create credentials?

How are you trying to auth from within your code? (please provide a snippet of your code )

Comment: Added Code and description @JohnHanley,@AndieVega

Comment: Hi Praneeth. Wondering if this is your blog post https://medium.com/@praneeth.jm/querying-in-the-cloud-using-bigquery-with-r-and-python-576541554967? So glad to see it and how you are sharing this knowledge! I added it to https://reddit.com/r/bigquery

Answer (score 1):

The option"googleAuthR.client_id" and "googleAuthR.client_secret" are changed by loading another library or setting them in a script, and then a cache file is used with different options set.

If you are always going to use the same credentials, make use of the auto authentication options by creating a cache token, moving it to a dedicated auth folder and using environment variables GAR_AUTH or package supported ones.

You can get more info in the following link: https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAuthR/articles/troubleshooting.html